# How to encode an unordered list of nominal category objects per sample for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Every sample in my dataset (*a user*) has a list of items (*skills*). Every item (*skill*) is a nominal category object (*skill-id* from 0 to 10000). Nominal category items are usually encoded for machine learning by hot encoding or binary encoding. However I have the problem that there is not only one item (*skill*) per sample (*user*) but also an unordered list of these items (*a list of skills*).

How do I encode these skill lists without having a large number of columns? Is there a trick to do so without factorisation techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A technique called feature hashing allows to map the objects into columns. It is described by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing:

```
 function hashing_vectorizer(features : array of string, N : integer):
 x := new vector[N]
 for f in features:
     h := hash(f)
     x[h mod N] += 1
 return x
```